# Programmatically pay a Dwolla account with API?

Tags: dwolla

I am working on an application where I would need to send funds via the API, if possible, programmatically. Is this possible with Dwolla?

Im not the developer so I'll explain best I can.  I think it would be similar to what's possible with Paypal's adaptive payments API.  Basically, as the owner of a Dwolla account, I need to send money to another Dwolla account using the application.  The receiver's Dwolla account#, payment amount, source, and my pin are all stored/generated from the application so that manually entering this information isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Our REST API's [Transactions / Send](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/send) method is exactly what you're looking for.  It allows you to send money on behalf of a Dwolla user programmatically.

The Send endpoint takes all the parameters you mentioned.  A request can be as simple as:

```
POST https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/transactions/send
Content-Type: application/json 

{
    "oauth_token": "Hyq7SiSHZ90i6seupTmhx8PPPykfuP94T5bSYW1XI9qvab7YQN",
    "pin": "1278",
    "destinationId": "812-713-9234",
    "amount": "309.21"
}
```

Note that this endpoint requires you to supply an OAuth token. Read about how they're obtained [here](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/auth).

Comment: You best add a disclaimer you're a developer to avoid downvotes.

Comment: what is a pricing of dwoll API for per transaction?